# Can salt just be appended to the password before hashing?

Tags: password-hashing, salt

I am currently developing the back end of a website for one my projects and needed to store passwords. I  knew that I needed to store passwords with salt, and my initial approach was to just generate the salt and append it to the password. However, to check that I wasn't being stupid I looked it up and saw a multitude of functions built into Node.js (the framework I'm using) to incorporate salt into hashing. Is there any reason I can't just append the salt to the password and if not can you please explain because I don't won't to just blindly do something? From my knowledge of hashing and salt, I see no reason why I couldn't do this.

Comment: Other than salts, Passwords should be hashed using slow hashing functions instead of regular cryptographic hashing functions. There are ready made functions which do the salting & also slow hash - best to use those instead of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 4):

There is much to be said against using a "normal" hash function for password hashing. The cracking would be accelerated. If you have a good reason to do so anyway, then appending the salt is probably not a relevant vulnerability.

If you use a password hashing algorithm, appending can cause problems. For example, Bcrypt simply cuts off the input (the password) over 56 bytes, so the salt could be truncated without you realizing it.